# Given a string, return true if the first instance of "x" in the string is immediately followed by another "x"

Tags: java

> Given a string, return `true` if the first instance of `"x"` in the string is immediately followed by another `"x"`. For example: `doubleX("xxxxx") → true`.

Below is my code which is working for every string except `"axxbb"`. It returns false for this string.

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'x')
            return true;

        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Remove the break and include a second if with a test if an x is present but not followed by a second x and return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems :

1. You break after the first iteration of the loop.
2. Even after you remove that break, you will return true if the first x is not followed by an x, but another x does (for example - `axaxxa` will wrongly return true).

A better implementation :

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)=='x')
            if (str.charAt(i+1)=='x') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: I have to break at the first instance of x as described in the question.

Comment: @Loki `return` does that.

Comment: @Loki You have a return statement, so you don't have to break. And your code breaks even if the first character is not an x.

Comment: So, the 2 problems are not actually problems. eg: doubleX("axxbb") → true
doubleX("axaxax") → false
doubleX("xxxxx") → true... it is just the first instance that i need. removing break wont help.

Comment: You can replace the inner `if` with `return str.charAt(i+1)=='x';`

Comment: @Loki Your code returns false for any input that doesn't start in "xx", so it doesn't work for most inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
int i = str.indexOf("x");
if (i == -1){
   return false;
}

if (i+1 >= str.length()) {
  return false;
}
return str.substring(i+1, i+2).equals("x");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex for simpler code. The "(\w)?" checks for any word character before the "xx" and "\w" checks for any word character after the matching "xx".

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  return str.matches("(\\w)?(xx)\\w*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this thread, but I was wondering why my code below can't pass all the unit tests. Thank you!

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    if (str.substring(i, i+2).equals("xx")){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Tests that are failed:

doubleX("xaxxx") → false (should be true)

doubleX("xaxx") →  false (should be true)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30788790)